# PHP-Script doesn't work for others - Blank canvas

Tags: php, facebook

quite funny error I get: my script works fine under my account. But on all (!) other account I just see a blank canvas. Here's my script:

```
<?php
require_once 'src/facebook.php'; 
$app_id = "xx";
$app_secret = "xx";  
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  'appId' => $app_id,  'secret' => $app_secret,  'cookie' => true  ));    
$signed_request = $facebook -> getSignedRequest();    
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];
if($locale =="de_DE") {
echo "<img src='deutsch.jpg'>";}
else {
echo "<img src='englisch.jpg'>";}
?>
```

Actually I can't find a failure in it. Do I have to change any permissions, or my canvas-url?

Comment: Maybe you have sandboxing enabled? Also, what does your error log say?

Comment: Sandboxing is not enabled... How do I get the error log? What is interesting: If I start the app it shows me the JPG-Image deutsch, due to my language setting. But all the others just see a blank page

Comment: The location depends on your system, on my machine it's under /var/log/apache2/error.log .

Answer (score 0):

1. Your App may be in Sandbox mode (in the developer app under 'Settings > Advanced'). This means that only developers (or testers) of the app can see it.
2. PHP errors - This might be happening because $signed_request["user"]["locale"] doesn't exist. Try adding

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', "1");
   ```

   to the top of your script and then see what the other users see.

Comment: 1. Sandboxing is disabled. 2. It doensn't show anything... Just a blank Canvas... I will make a screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24841978/Bildschirmfoto%202012-07-18%20um%2015.09.20.png

Comment: What is the response http status in case of a blank canvas?

Comment: Very interesting: If I use my account FireBug shows: GET app_xxx with HTTP Status 200 OK and one POST command with Status 200 OK. While using any other account, just the GET command appears, but with code 200 OK.